# Drawing very large graph

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I've got a very large directed graph in dot format.  Let's say 5 million nodes with ~50 million links.  I want to graph this with a reasonably small amount of overlap and reasonably short links whenever possible, no text labels, just pullet points for the nodes.  What tools could I use to visualize this?

I get that it's a huge amount of data, and it'll take a long time to crunch, but I'm hoping for it to take less than a week.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what you try to accomplish by plotting such as big graph. To my knowledge only the [OpenOrd layout](http://www.sandia.gov/~smartin/presentations/OpenOrd.pdf) will actually give something. An implementation exists in [Gephi](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=open+ORD) but you will never load millions of nodes in the GUI.

First, you can randomly subsample the graph to make the size manageable by taking one out of 100 nodes for instance, the graph structure should be consistent.

Second, you could also use [graph coarsening scheme](http://studiy.tu-cottbus.de/~clustering/algorithms:coarsening) to reduce the size of the network and browse the multi-layered graph. You could expand one node by clicking on it and only layout the subtree induced by the supernode.

Comment: Thanks for the quality links ! I've been able to compile OpenOrd - despite it's rather old - just adding the missing #include(s). Also the coarsening site is very nice